How would you say "pattern" in Latin?
An example of patterns I am talking about is the fact that the first two consonants in the Croatian river names are often 'k' and 'r', respectively: Krka, Korana, Kravarščica, Krapina, Krbavica, and two rivers named Karašica. Which Latin word would you use to describe it? Is it perhaps "regularitas"?
